# Shooting arrow probability

Tags: probability

There are two players X and Y each shoot 3 arrows at a circular target. What's the probability that the closet two arrows will be shot by X.

My approach: Total possibilities is 6! and 6 ways that first two are from X and 4! is the rest. So should be $6*\frac{4!}{6!} = \frac{1}{5}$.

Can someone check if this is correct?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! This is a great first question, but you can make math easier to read in the future by learning some basic MathJax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference!

Comment: I don´t think that you wanted to write closet.

Answer (score 1):

If we assume that, in order of closeness, all possibilities such as $$XXYYXYY$$ are equally likely then your answer is indeed correct.

Comment: This seems to be a necessary assumption to solve the problem as it is intended, but in reality this is a terrible assumption.  If $X$ is a champion archer and $Y$ had never even held a bow in his life, you should be quite sure that both of the two closest will have been from $X$.

Comment: Yes - even if they were (usually) of equal ability a good/poor first arrow might cause me to think they were not equal on the day.

Answer (score 0):

The probability the closest arrow is from $X$ is $1/2$.  Given that case, there are five remaining arrows, two from $X$, three from $Y$, so the chance the next closest is from $X$ is $2/5$.  Multiply these independent probabilities.